# How to find prediction interval when there is >1 response variable

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, random-forest, prediction-interval

I have been working on a data set where there is more than 1 response variable (multi-output). I used random forest for this model. The data set has 17 predictor variables and 2 output variables. I made the model using scikit learn RandomForestRegressor and made the prediction, but I am stuck at finding the prediction intervals for new data points. I went through papers by Wager (2014) and also on quantile regression forest, I found a library in python named [forestci](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/forest-confidence-interval/reference/forestci.html) which implements Wager (2014) and finds these intervals. But these papers and libraries don't discuss how we can find one for multiple response variables. I want to know how we can extend the prediction intervals for multi-output variables, so that I can make an uncertainty on my predicted responses. In the model I made, there are 17 predictors and 2 output variables.

- S. Wager, T. Hastie, B. Efron. “Confidence Intervals for Random Forests: The Jackknife and the Infinitesimal Jackknife”, Journal of Machine Learning Research vol. 15, pp. 1625-1651, 2014. ([pdf](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/wager14a/wager14a.pdf))

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are not interested in marginal prediction intervals, separately for your two outcomes.

You will need a two-dimensional analogue of a prediction interval, i.e., a *prediction area*. (Not an established term, I made that up right now.) Just as there are different prediction intervals (symmetric, shortest, one-sided, [Highest Density Regions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/148439/1352)), there are many different possible "prediction areas". One easily explained one would be a smallest prediction ellipse.

Since you are using nonparametric approaches, the simplest way would be to sample many bivariate points from your predictive bivariate density, then calculate a smallest ellipse covering a specific portion of those samples. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26810092/452096) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/256783/1352) may be helpful.

An alternative to the smallest prediction ellipse would be a two-dimensional Highest Density Region. [Hyndman (1996)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.1996.10474359?journalCode=utas20#), which I linked to in [this earlier answer on HDRs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148475/1352) goes into this.